# Error when retrieving data from SQLite database

Tags: android

I'm trying to get an SQLite database value on my mobile. The data is available in the database but this cursor class is showing values that are not available in the database. How do I solve the problem?

This is the `databasehelper` calling function

```
String imgname=img_name.getText().toString();
Cursor cursor = db.pname(imgname);

if(cursor.getCount()== 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Values are not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    while (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name"+cursor.getColumnIndex("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

`DatabaseHelpe`r class

```
public Cursor pname(String imgname) {
    String name = imgname.toString();
    String sql = "select * from '"+MSG+"' where product='"+name+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

I am expecting the name of my product. How do I fix it?

Comment: it is not clear which errors you get

Comment: What is the value of `MSG`? What is the value of `imgname`? Why are you not using `imgname` directly in the query, since the value will be identical to `name`? Can you log out the value of `sql` to Logcat?

Comment: MSG is products and imgname is IMG_20190210_200029.jpg and name is food

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `MSG` in single quotes. Your query should be:

```
select * from tablename where ...

String sql = "select * from "+MSG+" where product='"+name+"'";
```

`tablename` must not be in single quotes.